# Extracting data from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I just got my data and it is given to me as a `csv` file.

It looks like this in data studio(where the file was taken).

```
Counts  frequency
300     1
302     5
303     7
```

Excel can't handle the computations so that's why I'm trying to load it in python(it has `scipy` :D).

I want to load the data in an array:

```
Counts = [300, 302, 303]
frequency = [1, 5, 7]
```

How will I code this?

Answer (score 9):

Use the Python [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv) module.

Comment: my delimiter is `'` how do I use the `delimiter=` then?

Answer (score 7):

```
import csv

counts = []
frequencies = []

for d in csv.DictReader(open('yourfile.csv'), delimiter='\t'):
    counts.append(int(d['Counts']))
    frequencies.append(int(d['frequency']))

print 'Counts = ', counts
print 'frequency = ', frequencies
```

Comment: an error appears saying that there's no such file as data.csv

Comment: @wildfire: When using this code, perhaps you should include the actual name for your actual .csv file in your actual working directory.

Comment: @wildfire: of course you need to include the full path to the file on your system, instead of the example "yourfile.csv" I've put into the code.